# How do i get this span inside this li?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery tabs and trying to setup an indicator on the far right side of the tab to denote selected tab.  When i position a span at the end of the li, I will have css show it when :active/focus is met.  However the span shows up on the outside of the li.

How can i position the span inside the li?

```
  <li><a id='someId' href='#tabs-someId'>SomeValue</a><span class='butt'>&nbsp;</span></li>
```

here is the css for the span

```
.butt{
    background-color:green;
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
 }
```

Here is what the above line looks like

[image: image here]

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: why not: add border-right on active class of li? then you do not need span.

Comment: either do what techLove suggested or you could use `position: relative;` on `<li>` and `position:absolute;` on `<span>` then move accordingly

Comment: Why do you need to position the span with jQuery? Just put it in the original HTML as you showed. Use `.hide()` and `.show()` to control whether it's visible.

Comment: thats what im trying to do @barmar,  but the position of it is not correct.  ideally i want it a bit off the right side, vertically in the middle.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't reproduce the problem. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owgomo

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
 position: relative;
}
.butt{
  background-color:green;
  width:2px;
  height:2px;
  border-radius:2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
```